# email sent when qty is less than/ equal to 1 not working

Tags: php, sql, email

Hi i would want to create an if else statement in which if qty in tbl_product is less than 1, it will run the php code called "email.php". else, it will echo "Stocks still available". the current error now is that even when my database does not have a qty of 1, an email will still be sent to me. it would not echo "stocks available".

```
    <?php

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('ishop');
$qty = '1';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT qty FROM tbl_product");

 if($qty <= 1){
    include("email.php");
 }
 else{
     echo "Stocks Available";
}


?>
```

this is my email.php code

```
    <?php
   require_once "Mail.php";

   $from = '<gmail.gmail.com>';
   $to = '<gmail@gmail.com>';
   $subject = 'Hi!';
   $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

   $headers = array(
       'From' => $from,
       'To' => $to,
       'Subject' => $subject
   );

   $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
           'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
           'port' => '465',
           'auth' => true,
           'username' => 'gmail@gmail.com',
           'password' => 'pw'
       ));

   $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

   if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
       echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
   } else {
       echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}


?>
```

Comment: Narrow the question down. It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `include()` for this.

```
if($qty <= 5){
   include("testmail.php");
}
else{
    echo "Stocks Available";
}
```

For more reference, see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";
    $flag = 0;
    $send_email = 0;
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if($row['qty'] <= 1){
                 if($send_email == 0){
                     include("email.php");
                     $send_email = 1;
                 }
            } else{
              if($flag == 0)
                 $flag = 1;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    if($flag && $send_email == 0)// new edit.
    echo "Stocks Available";
    $conn->close();
```

?>

Comment: for your reference, just to check, keep `testmail.php` inside if condition.. And check whats hapening.

Comment: Is the code working if it is kept inside the `if()`??

Comment: you still have same error??

Comment: nope i do not have the previous error already, the current error now is that even when my database does not have a qty of 1, an email will still be sent to me. it will not echo "stocks still available".

Comment: you have give, `$qty = '1';` in php code... remove that...

Comment: this error would pop out: Undefined variable: qty

Comment: you shud add the line after the query

Comment: $qty = "value from database";

Comment: is there any possible way to POST the qty in database to $qty instead of hard coding a number to it?

Comment: ya... i ll edit my answer, please check that

Comment: You have to loop all the products in your db??

Comment: what do you mean by loop? sorry i am new in php ;_;

Comment: you want to check this for all products ?? or only 1 product??

Comment: then its easy use mysqli_fetch_assoc() and inside the while(), add this if() and else()

Comment: do you mind updating your code with the mysqli_fetch_assoc()? :)

Comment: I will do it. Check the answer in some time...

Comment: @p0ny, first change `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`, use this, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp. Then we can write our logic.

Comment: check the answer now.

Comment: thankyou! :) it works now, just that there is alot of echos right now. "Stocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks AvailableStocks" how do i stop so many echos haha

Comment: take a variable outside while loop. $flag = 0; in else part, make $flag = 1;then outside the while, `if($flag) echo "Stocks Available";`

Comment: If answer was helpful, please consider accpeting the answer.

Comment: sorry do you mind updating your ans to the if flag part again, because i tried adding it in, but i can't seem to get it!

Comment: now i have a lot of messages sent to my inbox when i changed the qty to 5 which is correct. but it's sending too many messages.

Comment: you want only once??

Comment: yes! only one email to be sent to me when the qty is more than 5.

Comment: i have added  one more flag. `$send_email`, see that

Comment: thankyou, but now both echos are being displayed :/

Comment: email sent success fully?? if u dont want that you can remove that.

Comment: Message successfully sent!
Stocks Available

these two

Comment: remove message sent successfully

Comment: cause now i changed if($row['qty'] <= 5){ to 5, so it will send a message to my email, it should not echo "stocks available"

Comment: which ever echo you dont wnt, you can remove it.

Comment: nope, cause now my database has a qty=1, and it sends the email, but it should not echo out "stocks available" since stocks are not available.

Comment: it is doing that because you have many products, for each product its checking, some products having more that 5 quantity, for that product its printing that line.

Comment: for eg, when the email is sent, i don't want the echo of "stocks available"